# Error al consumir servicio en ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, linq, servicio, postman

Buenas tardes con todos , estoy creando servicio para mostrar los datos de perfil de mi usuario guardados en mi base de datos , estoy utilizando Linq para hacer el procedimiento , pero no me esta retornando los datos del usuario registrado y me retorna error , creé mi interfaces repository y service para poder llamar a la función en mi controlador y poder tener todo mas ordenado , solo en el controlador estoy mandando llamar a la función que se encuentra en mi repository

este es mi servicio

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Salesws.Context;
using Salesws.Models;
using Salesws.Service;
using Salesws.Service.Interfaces;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace Salesws.RestControllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class LoginController : ControllerBase
    {

        private IConfiguration _config;
        //Contexto de la base de datos SVM
        private readonly SVMcontext _context;
        private readonly IFechaService _fechaService;
        private readonly ILambSelLiquidacionService _iamb_Sel_Liquidacion;
        private readonly IPokectCargaService _pokectService;
        public LoginController(IConfiguration config, SVMcontext context,IFechaService fechaService,ILambSelLiquidacionService amb_Sel_LiquidacionService,IPokectCargaService pokectService)
        {
            _config = config;
            _context = context;
            _fechaService = fechaService;
            _iamb_Sel_Liquidacion = amb_Sel_LiquidacionService;
            //pokectservice
            _pokectService = pokectService;
            
        }

        //buscar Usuario por id 
        //servicio buscar perfil
        //[Authorize]
        [HttpGet("ugv_GetSetDSyncPerfil/{id}")]
        public ActionResult ugv_GetSetDSyncPerfil(string id)
        {
            var usuario = _pokectService.getDSCargaPerfil(id);
            return Ok(usuario);
        }
    }
}
```

este es mi interface repository

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Salesws.Service.Interfaces
{
    public interface IPokectCargaRepository
    {
        public string getDSCargaPerfil(string id);

    }
}
```

este es mi interface servicio

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Salesws.Service.Interfaces
{
    public interface IPokectCargaService
    {
        public string getDSCargaPerfil(string id);
    }
}
```

este es mi servicio

```
using Salesws.Service.Interfaces;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Salesws.Service
{
    public class PokectCargaService : IPokectCargaService
    {
        private readonly IPokectCargaRepository _pokectRepository;
        public PokectCargaService(IPokectCargaRepository pokectRepository)
        {
            _pokectRepository = pokectRepository;
        }

        public string getDSCargaPerfil(string id)
        {
            return _pokectRepository.getDSCargaPerfil(id);
        }
    }
}
```

este es mi repositorio

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Salesws.Context;
using Salesws.Service.Interfaces;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Salesws.Repository
{
    public class PokectCargaRepository :IPokectCargaRepository
    {
        private readonly SVMcontext _context;
        public PokectCargaRepository(SVMcontext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public string getDSCargaPerfil(string id)
        {
            var data = "{}";
            try
            {
                var qry = from usuario in _context.AfcmaPersonas
                          where usuario.CodUsuario.Equals(id)
                          select usuario;

                return qry.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
            return data;
        }

    }
}
```

este es el error que me sale en el postman , me da ok pero no me muestra los datos del usuario
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que `qry` es la instancia de la *query*. Lo que devuelves es el `ToString` de la *query*, no del objeto `AfcmaPersonas`.

En tu caso, si sólo quieres recibir una única instancia, puedes usar `FirstOrDefault`.

```
public string getDSCargaPerfil(string id)
{
    var data = "{}";
    try
    {
        var qry = from usuario in _context.AfcmaPersonas
                  where usuario.CodUsuario.Equals(id)
                  select usuario;

        // Devuelve la primera entrada o null, si no encuentra ninguna.
        var user = qry.FirstOrDefault();
        // En este punto, puedes trabajar con user, serializándolo a JSON o lo que necesites.
        return user?.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception e) { }
    return data;
}
```

---

**Edit 1**
Como decía en el comentario, si usas `ToString` y no implementas ese método, sólo te va a devolver el nombre de la clase...

Para serializarlo en JSON, puedes usar el paquete de [`Newtonsoft`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm)

```
public string getDSCargaPerfil(string id)
{
    var data = "{}";
    try
    {
        var qry = from usuario in _context.AfcmaPersonas
                  where usuario.CodUsuario.Equals(id)
                  select usuario;

        // Devuelve la primera entrada o null, si no encuentra ninguna.
        var user = qry.FirstOrDefault();
        string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception e) { }
    return data;
}
```

Por otra parte, puedes implementar el método `ToString`

```
public class AfcmaPersona
{
    // ...
    
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
}
```

No te olvides de añadir el paquete de *Newtonsoft* y agregar el `using`.

Espero que sirva.

Comment: me regresa Salesws.ModelsSVM.AfcmaPersona , ya no me regresa lo anterior , es la tabla donde estan los datos del usuario

Comment: Eso es porque no has implementado nada en el `ToString`... Como ponía en la respuesta, puedes serializarlo en JSON (que es lo más común): `return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);`